# Dynamic default value setting for a flask form field

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to set the default value for a string field in flask wtforms. The following is my code and it doesn't work.

**Code:**

```py
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField
class TestForm(Form):
     test = StringField('Test field')

@app.route('display/')
def display():
    dynamicvalue = getdynamicvalue()
    return render_template('test.html', form = form, defname = dynamicvalue)
```

**test.html:**

```html
<div class="controls">
  {{ form.test(size=80, readonly="readonly", value={{defname}} }}
</div>
```

How do I correct this?

The following is the error

```
{{form.test(size=80, readonly= "readonly", value={{defname}}  }}
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

Comment: You could instead set the value in Python code: `form.test.data = dynamicvalue`.

Comment: look at the answer by me in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576935/can-i-set-a-stringfields-default-value-outside-the-field-constructor/60660725#60660725).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you should use one pair of `{{ }}` brackets in template

```
<div class="controls">
  {{ form.test(size=80, readonly="readonly", value=defname) }}
</div>
```